# Image Buttons Have Low Resolution Quality

Tags: android, image, resolution, android-studio

I'm using Synfig Animator to draw my animations for my android game
I'm also using Android Studio to write the code for it, However.
On testing, the images that i'm using looks very bad and unfocused even though i made them on a high resolution,
I've tried to change the resolution of it but it didn't work!
and when i change the size it just get bigger and stay the same..
How can i fix this problem? i need to have perfect animations for my game.

Comment: Sounds like they're getting compressed.  You'll need to look at the image properties and find any kind of compression settings.  It's probably being very aggressive and you'll want to change it back to 100%, true color, uncompressed, or similar.  Its also possible that the maximum size is smaller than the true size, e.g. if the max size is 128x128 and your button texture is 512x64 native, then it's getting scaled down to 1/4 of its original size and some loss of quality occurs.

Comment: isn't scaling down is better than scaling up for the image resolution?

Comment: For GUI elements you want *no* scaling.  And "maximum size" is just that, a maximum.  Images larger are scaled down while smaller ones are left alone.  I'm not familiar with  android studio, but I would imagine it has some kind of image compression in order to save space: all editor studios do.  Unity uses DXT, Flash uses JPG by default (with PNG available), the Source Engine uses VTF (which is more than just compression, but it does compress the image data).